# Error due to bootstrap installation in angularjs

Tags: angularjs

I have following dependencies in my Angularjs code.

```
"angular": "1.5.10",
"angular-route": "1.5.10",
"angular-cookies": "1.5.10",
"angular-translate": "^2.13.1",
"angular-translate-loader-static-files": "^2.13.1",
"bootstrap": "^3.3.7"
```

and below is the code in app.js

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', ['ngRoute', 'ngCookies', 'pascalprecht.translate']);
```

Everything is working fine and it can be http://pankaj.in

Now, I am trying to add Navbar and for that I am following this link: https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/

and after installing, the final dependency list is below.

```
"angular": "1.5.10",
"angular-route": "1.5.10",
"angular-cookies": "1.5.10",
"angular-translate": "^2.13.1",
"angular-translate-loader-static-files": "^2.13.1",
"bootstrap": "^3.3.7",
"angular-animate": "1.5.10",
"angular-touch": "1.5.10"
```

and below is the code in app.js

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', ['ngRoute', 'ngCookies', 'pascalprecht.translate', 
'ngAnimate', 'ngTouch', 'ui.bootstrap']);
```

but due to some reasons, I am getting errors as listed here: **[Error details](https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$injector/modulerr?p0=myApp&p1=Error:%20%5B$injector:modulerr%5D%20http:%2F%2Ferrors.angularjs.org%2F1.5.10%2F$injector%2Fmodulerr%3Fp0%3Dui.bootstrap%26p1%3DError%253A%2520%255B%2524injector%253Anomod%255D%2520http%253A%252F%252Ferrors.angularjs.org%252F1.5.10%252F%2524injector%252Fnomod%253Fp0%253Dui.bootstrap%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520at%2520http%253A%252F%252Flocalhost%253A85%252FMyProjects%252FProjects%252FLearning%252FAPI%252Fpublic%252Fbower_components%252Fangular%252Fangular.min.js%253A6%253A426%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520at%2520http%253A%252F%252Flocalhost%253A85%252FMyProjects%252FProjects%252FLearning%252FAPI%252Fpublic%252Fbower_components%252Fangular%252Fangular.min.js%253A25%253A235%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520at%2520b%2520(http%253A%252F%252Flocalhost%253A85%252FMyProjects%252FProjects%252FLearning%252FAPI%252Fpublic%252Fbower_components%252Fangular%252Fangular.min.js%253A24%253A282)%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520at%2520http%253A%252F%252Flocalhost%253A85%252FMyProjects%252FProjects%252FLearning%252FAPI%252Fpublic%252Fbower_components%252Fangular%252Fangular.min.js%253A25%253A20%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520at%2520http%253A%252F%252Flocalhost%253A85%252FMyProjects%252FProjects%252FLearning%252FAPI%252Fpublic%252Fbower_components%252Fangular%252Fangular.min.js%253A40%253A17%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520at%2520q%2520(http%253A%252F%252Flocalhost%253A85%252FMyProjects%252FProjects%252FLearning%252FAPI%252Fpublic%252Fbower_components%252Fangular%252Fangular.min.js%253A7%253A371)%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520at%2520g%2520(http%253A%252F%252Flocalhost%253A85%252FMyProjects%252FProjects%252FLearning%252FAPI%252Fpublic%252Fbower_components%252Fangular%252Fangular.min.js%253A39%253A382)%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520at%2520http%253A%252F%252Flocalhost%253A85%252FMyProjects%252FProjects%252FLearning%252FAPI%252Fpublic%252Fbower_components%252Fangular%252Fangular.min.js%253A40%253A34%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520at%2520q%2520(http%253A%252F%252Flocalhost%253A85%252FMyProjects%252FProjects%252FLearning%252FAPI%252Fpublic%252Fbower_components%252Fangular%252Fangular.min.js%253A7%253A371)%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520at%2520g%2520(http%253A%252F%252Flocalhost%253A85%252FMyProjects%252FProjects%252FLearning%252FAPI%252Fpublic%252Fbower_components%252Fangular%252Fangular.min.js%253A39%253A382)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20http:%2F%2Flocalhost:85%2FMyProjects%2FProjects%2FLearning%2FAPI%2Fpublic%2Fbower_components%2Fangular%2Fangular.min.js:6:426%0A%20%20%20%20at%20http:%2F%2Flocalhost:85%2FMyProjects%2FProjects%2FLearning%2FAPI%2Fpublic%2Fbower_components%2Fangular%2Fangular.min.js:40:292%0A%20%20%20%20at%20q%20(http:%2F%2Flocalhost:85%2FMyProjects%2FProjects%2FLearning%2FAPI%2Fpublic%2Fbower_components%2Fangular%2Fangular.min.js:7:371)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20g%20(http:%2F%2Flocalhost:85%2FMyProjects%2FProjects%2FLearning%2FAPI%2Fpublic%2Fbower_components%2Fangular%2Fangular.min.js:39:382)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20http:%2F%2Flocalhost:85%2FMyProjects%2FProjects%2FLearning%2FAPI%2Fpublic%2Fbower_components%2Fangular%2Fangular.min.js:40:34%0A%20%20%20%20at%20q%20(http:%2F%2Flocalhost:85%2FMyProjects%2FProjects%2FLearning%2FAPI%2Fpublic%2Fbower_components%2Fangular%2Fangular.min.js:7:371)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20g%20(http:%2F%2Flocalhost:85%2FMyProjects%2FProjects%2FLearning%2FAPI%2Fpublic%2Fbower_components%2Fangular%2Fangular.min.js:39:382)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20fb%20(http:%2F%2Flocalhost:85%2FMyProjects%2FProjects%2FLearning%2FAPI%2Fpublic%2Fbower_components%2Fangular%2Fangular.min.js:43:381)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20c%20(http:%2F%2Flocalhost:85%2FMyProjects%2FProjects%2FLearning%2FAPI%2Fpublic%2Fbower_components%2Fangular%2Fangular.min.js:21:19)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20Gc%20(http:%2F%2Flocalhost:85%2FMyProjects%2FProjects%2FLearning%2FAPI%2Fpublic%2Fbower_components%2Fangular%2Fangular.min.js:21:332)**

Am I missing something?

Comment: can't see angular bootstrap in there..

Comment: if we open this link: https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/ you will see fourth bullet point: Bootstrap CSS (tested with version 3.3.7). Should I install that also?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add ui bootstrap js file

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-bootstrap/2.5.0/ui-bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Or use npm to install it:

```
npm install angular-ui-bootstrap
```

Comment: I am using bower, should I use `bower install angular-ui-bootstrap` ?

Comment: @PankajGarg I would suggest you raise another question explaining your findings